# Nginx Stripping POST body on proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, proxypass

I have a server running behind a firewall, with a single external IP, which therefore has requests proxied by domain through via an Nginx box.

When I run cURL behind the firewall, everything goes to plan:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The cURL is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @test.json 111.111.111.111/endpoint/ -i
```

As soon as I run this in Postman/Hurl.it/whatever from outside the network, I get `400` errors. The code throws a `400` when it is missing the POST body (JSON). Echoing this out shows that no JSON is being received.

The relevant Nginx configuration is thus:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  domain.co;
  location / {
        proxy_pass             http://111.111.111.111/;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
  }
}
```

The domain does sit behind CloudFlare, and I've switched it to DNS only and tried that - I'd be very surprised if that was the issue.

I've had a look at other solutions, and tried some stuff out but I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, unless I fundamentally misunderstand how `proxy_pass` works?

Comment: So it turns out a GET is being made as in https://serverfault.com/questions/434205/nginx-https-rewrite-turns-post-to-get however, one would have expected this to work fine, given: https://serverfault.com/questions/434205/nginx-https-rewrite-turns-post-to-get#comment466705_434210